# UWP Binding to Observable Collection of UserControl not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have this page: `NewsPage`

```
<Page
x:Class="TouchTypeRacing.Views.NewsPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TouchTypeRacing.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="using:TouchTypeRacing.Controls"
xmlns:models="using:TouchTypeRacing.Models"
DataContext="{Binding}"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="White">
    ....
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  Margin="5,10,5,0">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}"
                      x:Name="itemsControl">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Post">
                    <controls:Post/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

The page's datacontext is bound to a view model. `PageViewmModel`
The `ItemsControl` datatemplate is a `Post` control.
The `ItemsSource` of the `ItemsControl` on the page is bound to the `Posts` property of the viewmodel.

```
public NewsPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    _viewModel = new NewsPageViewModel();
    DataContext = _viewModel;           
}
```

Then, the view model:

```
public class NewsPageViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Post> _posts = new ObservableCollection<Post>();
    public ObservableCollection<Post> Posts { get { return _posts; } }
    public NewsPageViewModel()
    {
        GetPosts(_posts);
    }
    public static void GetPosts(ObservableCollection<Post> posts)
    {
        posts.Clear();
        posts = new ObservableCollection<Post>
        {
            new Post
            {
                Id = "1",
                DateTime = DateTime.Today,
                User = Application.CurrentUser,
                Likes = 10,
                ImagePath = Application.CurrentUser.ImagePath,
                Message = "Test message",
                Comments = new ObservableCollection<Comment>
                {
                    new Comment {Id= "1", Content="Comment1", User = Application.CurrentUser },
                    new Comment {Id= "2", Content="Comment2", User = Application.CurrentUser },
                    new Comment {Id= "3", Content="Comment3", User = Application.CurrentUser },
                    new Comment {Id= "4", Content="Comment4", User = Application.CurrentUser },
                },
                Last2Comments = new List<Comment>
                {
                    new Comment {Id= "3", Content="Comment3", User = Application.CurrentUser },
                    new Comment {Id= "4", Content="Comment4", User = Application.CurrentUser },
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

The `ItemsControl` shows up empty. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep switching collections, `NewsPageViewModel` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` when you change collection instances. Here's how that goes. I've also included a much simpler "quick fix" solution below.

```
public class VIewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}

public class NewsPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public NewsPageViewModel()
    {
        Posts = GetPosts();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Post> _posts;
    public ObservableCollection<Post> Posts
    {
        get { return _posts; }
        set {
            _posts = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected ObservableCollection<Post> GetPosts()
    {
        //  do stuff to get posts, return new ObservableCollection<Post>
    }
}
```

## Quick Fix

Easier is to start out with a collection instance so the UI gets something the first (and in this case, ONLY) time it grabs the value of `Posts`, keep the same collection. However, without `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you're going to run into no end of issues like this. Trying to use WPF without it is really an exercise in self-punishment.

```
ObservableCollection<Post> _posts = new ObservableCollection<Post>();

public ObservableCollection<Post> Posts { get { return _posts; } }
public NewsPageViewModel()
{
    GetPosts(_posts);
}
public static void GetPosts(ObservableCollection<Post> posts)
{
    posts.Clear();
    //  ...get posts
}
```

The special thing about `ObservableCollection` is that it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which will notify the UI when you add or remove items from the collection -- but the UI has to know which collection to listen to for changes.

Comment: Still does not show anything. I've edited the Viewmodel as in your quickfix. Check edit

Comment: @shadowCODE You  call `posts.Clear()` and then you throw it away and replace the parameter with a new collection. Don't do that. That will have no effect on anything outside the method where you do it. Put the post in the OLD collection. You must, must, must, must keep the SAME collection for that fix to work. In that code, the collection you start with is the only collection the UI will EVER know about. So that's the one the posts must go in. This is one reason why that's not a great solution.

Comment: @shadowCODE See "exercise in self-punishment" above.

Comment: Doing `posts.Add(new Post())` in `GetPosts()` - to keep the same post as you've said - crashes the app.

Comment: @shadowCODE What's the exception? Is `posts` null?

Comment: @shadowCODE is that exact -- I mean, in the new post, are `Comments` and `Last2Comments` null? Anyway, look at the stack trace on the exception, see where it's thrown, see what the problem is. ObservableCollection.Add doesn't throw exceptions unless you call it on a null reference.

Comment: `Comment` and `Last2Comments` are not null. They are initialized to collections of `Comment` in new posts.  
Running in debug ends in  
`#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) => ...`  
Stepping further - `A debugger is attached to this x.exe but not configured to debug this unhandled exception`

Comment: @shadowCODE Please put a try/catch around everything inside `GetPosts`, put a breakpoint in the catch, and see exactly what happened. What you pasted in is not where the exception was thrown. That's the unhandled exception handler stuff.

Comment: @shadowCODE Also, *what* exception is it? Unhandled isn't a type of exception. What does it say actually went wrong? What is the type of the exception? What is the message for the exception?

Comment: Exception is not from `GetPosts()`. Still ends up in the unhandled exception handler.

Comment: @shadowCODE Hmmm. Sounds like it's something that you just never hit until you had something in that collection. What's in the stack trace? What is the type of the exception? What is the message?

Comment: Exception type: `Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs`  
Message: `Message = "Value does not fall within the expected range."`  
StackTrace: `null`

Comment: @shadowCODE Might be something in your controls:Post view. That would explain why it started happening when you finally got a Post into the ItemsControl.

Comment: Yeah, i had a funny declaration. I set the width of an ellipse to `{Binding width, ElementName=grid}` where the ellipse is in the grid and the width of the grid is automatic. I have it working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments yet...so:

In the constructor of the NewsPageViewModel you initialize a new (but empty) ObservableCollection.

If you are not adding elements in the GetPost-Method, _posts will stay empty.